# Почему возвращаемая строка содержит undefined?

Tags: javascript, строки, функции

Недавно начал изучать JS и столкнулся с поведением в функции, которое мне не совсем понятно. Как параметр функция принимает массив из хэштегов, среди которых она ищет уникальные, и затем возвращает список таких хэштегов в виде строки (хэштеги разделяет запятая).

```
const separator = ", ";

function normalizeHashtags(hashtags) {

var uniqueValues = hashtags.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return hashtags.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

var normalizedHashtags;

for(var i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++){
    if(i == uniqueValues.length - 1){
        normalizedHashtags += uniqueValues[i];
    } else{
        normalizedHashtags += uniqueValues[i] + separator;
    }
}

return normalizedHashtags;
```

}

Значение возвращаемой строки должно выглядеть следующим образом: `tag1, tag2, tag3`. Но, вместо этого я получал `undefinedtag1, tag2, tag3`.

Методом проб и ошибок я выяснил, что если строку  `var normalizedHashtags;`
изменить на
`var normalizedHashtags = "";`, то можно получить желаемый результат. Нужно ли всегда поступать подобным образом и постоянно инициализировать переменные при их объявлении в JS?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно инициализировать переменную перед ее использованием

```
var normalizedHashtags = "";
```

значение, которое считывается при операции конкатенации строк, нужно всегда инициализировать. Вы можете не инициализировать переменные (в других случаях), тогда переменная будет принимать значение `undefined`.

Comment: А если переменная будет представлять массив? Что произойдет если я, скажем, не буду инициализировать переменную при объявлении, но потом захочу поместить в неё массив из целочисленных значений или строк? Что произойдёт с этим undefined?

Comment: надо инициализировать, а то будет `undefined`.